# regex when format is not fixed

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an output which structure varies (nbr of spaces before and after the equal sign, single quote or double quote)

```
 product description = "flsdfjldsjs fd fs"
 product description="fdsfsd"
 product description =""
 product description ='lfjdsdljfldsf'
 product description =''
 product description='fldsjfl'
 product description=''
 etc ...
```

How can i use regex to match the string between the quotes or the empty string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match it with...

```
str.match(/(['"])(.*?)\1/);
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?2vvdb).

Comment: @gilly3 In case two sets of quote find their way in. I want to be ungreedy.

Comment: What if the line is: product description = "abc \"def\" ghi"?

Comment: Good, but make sure to capture the match since the question is how "to match the string between the quotes".

Comment: @yogsototh Then you probably want something a little more complex than  a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
^product description *= *['"](.*?)['"] *$
```

And the string is in capturing group 1.

The `*` before and after the = sign means "any number of spaces", and the `['"]` means "match  a " or a '".

Comment: Try replacing the ` *` with `\s*` to match tabs as well.

Comment: Firstly -- by my reading, the OP needs help actually *using* the regex. Some JavaScript sample code might help. Secondly -- your regex assumes that the string contains neither double-quotes nor single-quotes. I suspect that that's not a valid assumption.

Comment: This will match a string containing both double quotes and single quotes. It assumes that there's one `product description = ' .... '` per line and always matches the outer two quotes, so there can be nested quotes inside (note that it is anchored at end of line).

Answer (score 0):

Coffee is right, but to make it more specific, you can try:

```
var reg = /^product description *= *(("[^"]*")|('[^']*')) *$/
```

That way you don't run into problems if you encounter " inside ' or viceversa, as in "John's"  or '"hi"'.

Answer (score 0):

This will match the string with the quotes:

```
/['"].*['"]/
```

To match only what is inside you should use groups.

```
/['"](.*)['"]/
```

Which you use like this:

```
var myString = "position='abc de f'";
var myRegexp = /['"](.*)['"]/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[0]);  // abc de f
```